# How to float list items towards top of page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to have a list item floating towards the top rather than the natural flow that makes it flow towards top. If you visit the link below I have created a list of items.

http://jsfiddle.net/subash1232/wQL9w/23/

I want one to start in the bottom right of the div and other items floating towards left. when the line is full then it needs to go up rather than down.

Is it even possible?
Thanks a lot already.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wQL9w/24/) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Starx not really. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. You need to reverse order of elements in your html. You can do it manually or using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could always write your list elements in reverse order. I believe this would get you the desired results if it wasn't too much of an inconvenience.